# ClearCase : Making new baseline with old baseline activities

Tags: clearcase

In an integration stream Int , A1,A2,A3 are activities,B1 is baseline that includes A1,A2,A3 activities.

(Int Stream)-----A1------A2------------------A3------[B1]---------------->

We are going to deploy new version of software and our project manager said that he did not 
want to include A2 activity changeset in this version of software.

Can we create new baseline B2 that only includes A1 and A3 activities in ClearCase?

(Int Stream)-----A1------------------------A3------[B2]----------------> ?

Comment: Added comment on "activity dependency" as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Since B1 exists, all activities are "linked" by a common "timeline", and ClearCase will ask you to also include A2.

A possible solution would be to create a sub-stream, and to make a `findmerge` with only A1 and A3
(a `findmerge` is a non-UCM merge that can still take a list of UCM activities as an input)

The fundation baseline of the sub-stream should be the last baseline (produced on IntStream) *not* including A1, A2 and A3.

Then:

```
ct findmerge activity:A1@\pvob activity:A3@\pvob -fcsets -c "report for delivery" -merge -gmerge
```

That sub-stream plays the role of a "release stream", or "consolidation stream", that is a stream which will include all you need to build a final release.

The parent stream (IntStream) goes on in its role of integrating all development effort (coming from other sub-streams)

---

Note:

- "pvob" is meant to be replace by the name of your project vob (the vob containing all UCM datas like projects, streams, baseline, activities, ...)
- "`ct`" stands for "cleartool": it is an `alias` (Unix) or a `doskey` (Windows version of an alias: `doskey ct=cleartool $*`)

---

**Activity dependency**: A3 could in this case have some versions based on A2 versions.

`findmerge` command only uses activities for their `changeset` (list of versions) to be merged:

> Each version listed in a change set becomes the from-version in a merge operation. As always, the to-version is the one in your view.

A3 including changes made in A2, the final result will include A1, A2 and A3 changes, except if A1 and A3 changes are "concurrent" (changes on similar lines): in this case, a non-trivial merge will need to be performed.

---

Since you do not want A2 changes, you need, as you mention in the comments, to complete that `findmerge` operation with a perl utility script `cset.pl`:

```
ccperl cset.pl -undo A2
```

It will perform a "negative merge" (or "substractive merge"), removing any changes for A2.

Comment: Yes I tried and it worked.Thank you very much. You are much more helpful than IBM Turkey office :)

Comment: for example I have a file like Tree.txt.  in A1 Activity I added 3 lines of code to Tree.txt, in A2 activity I added 2 lines to same file and A3 I added 5 lines of code.
 When I try to do "findmerge A1 A3" like above, the Merged Tree.txt file includes lines that I added with A1,A2,A3 .?

Comment: I used "cset.pl -undo A2" command and it deleted changeset from A2 activity so final file only contains lines from A1 and A3 activity. it worked great.