# How to find ClearCase activity's dependents?

Tags: clearcase

As you know, sometimes a UCM activity depends on another activity, and sometimes other activities are depended on that activity. I'm wondering how can I get this information easily?
Assuming my input is an activity ID - how do I get these two outputs easily?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The activity dependency is determined in the context of a deliver or rebase.

See "[About activity dependencies in the deliver operation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_activity_depend.htm)

[image: deliver activity dependency]

So maybe the easiest way to see what activities are involved is to do a `deliver -preview`.

But beside that, there is no easy way to list those dependencies because they involve:

- version dependency (the same file has versions in both activities, making one depending on the other)
- [timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643968/clearcase-ucm-cross-delivering-vs-delivering-upwards) (see for instance "[ClearCase : Making new baseline with old baseline activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684895/clearcase-making-new-baseline-with-old-baseline-activities)"): a baseline made by a deliver/rebase and which will link (that is the second form of dependencies) *all* the activities in a given stream together. Even if they don't have any file in common.

Answer (score 0):

```
REM output is space delimited list

view-context> cleartool lsact -fmt "%[contrib_acts]p" activityID@\pvob
act1 act2
```

If you make (mkbl) and compare (diffbl -act) baselines, you can obtain the same information as well as recursive delivery information.

From ClearCase GUIs (Project Explorer and ClearCase Explorer -> My Activities, you can also right click on an activity and select "Show Contributing Activities".

This answer only addresses one direction for activities.  Using baselines with other %[xxx]p format specifiers for baselines should allow forward and reverse resolution.