# Can a non owner of the clearcase activity deliver activity

Tags: clearcase-ucm

We are planning to setup Clearcase UCM like below

Int (uat/prod env)
 - test (for test env)
 - dev (for dev env)

Developer will be delivering their activities to dev stream. Then we as an administrator deliver the activities from dev stream to test stream. Do a build deploy in test environment. Everything goes fine then deliver activities to int stream do a build there, test in uat environment and then deploy to production.

My question is should we as admin be able to deliver developers activities from dev stream to test stream and then int stream or only owner of the activity is allowed to deliver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or only owner of the activity is allowed to deliver.

No, any ClearCase user can deliver activities or baselines from one Stream to another.
You just need to have a `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable correctly set to the group (main or secondary) of the vob and pvob involved in your UCM project.

Beware though of partial deliveries: if you deliver only some activities (and not all of them each time) from dev to test, you risk to introduce artificial dependencies between those (delivered) activities and the other (not yet delivered) ones on the dev stream.
See "[ClearCase : Making new baseline with old baseline activities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684895/6309)", and the notion of "timeline". That was true for ClearCase 6.x and 7.x, it may have changed for ClearCase 8.x.