# How to move a clearcase acivity with its changeset to a different view?

Tags: clearcase

I am currently trying to clear up a mess where a new starter has (almost) completed a change, so it's been through review/rework and is ready for deliver, but in the meantime, like most people familiar with modern SCM systems, he's just started a new activity on the same view. (and he's on leave)

I believe the solution to this is to move the new activity with its changeset to a new view and then deliver the old activity as intended.

However I have read how to "move" an activity between streams, but I can't find in the IBM docs or anywhere else how to move it with the changeset.

Now, the fallback option is to manually copy over the change and remove it from the first view. I'd rather not do this as that adds dev and review effort, but if it is the only way, then I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed "[Moving a set activity from one view/stream to different a view/stream](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/moving-set-activity-one-viewstream-different-viewstream)"

But regarding "change sets", you might have to [move UCM version in a change set from one activity to another](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/moving-ucm-version-change-set-one-activity-another), i order to empty one (change set, from one activity) to another.
Not ideal, but depending on the size of the change set, feasible.

Comment: Moving changesets between streams isn't possible without doing "create and set activity, checkout, copy-or-merge, and checkin". This is because the change sets are versions on the stream's branch. This would effectively be the "findmerge ... -fcsets ..." anyway.

Comment: @BrianCowan Agreed. That reminded me of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697198/6309).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to deliver the changes, and they are all checked in, you can just:.

1. Create/Set an activity in either the integration or other stream view.
2. CD into the view, and into the VOB containing the majority of the files you're delivering.
3. Run cleartool findmerge activity:myactivity@/vobs/mypvob -fcsets -merge

If any are checked out, you would need access to the view to perform the checkin, and if you have that (and appropriate access rights), you can perform the deliver yourself.