# UCM: How to exclude files from a ClearCase deliver

Tags: clearcase-ucm

We have several Activities that have versions of files associated with them that we do not want to deliver to the Integration Stream because they're not needed (they were only needed during troubleshooting in the local environment).

However, even though the ClearQuest records are in the Closed state, they continue to show up as candidates during a delivery. How can we prevent this?

I'd rather not have to create a new element type "never merge" and execute chtype commands on each file we don't want to merge.

Answer (score 0):

See "[ClearCase : Making new baseline with old baseline activities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684895/6309)": if some of those activities were previously delivered (Dev to Int), then *all* of the Activities on Dev are now linked by a "timeline", which make them all candidate for deliver.

One solution is to findmerge each activity individually (non-UCM merge)

But a better long-term solution is to make sure that any troubleshooting activity is done in a sub-stream instead of being done and mixed with the other activities on the Dev stream.

Comment: The problem was caused by developers re-using Activities that were already delivered and associating debugging code with them. We don't allow that anymore. I agree that debugging code should not be checked into the regular development stream. 

I was hoping there was a easy way in which ClearCase could be told to ignore those particular Activities (or versions) during a deliver though.

Comment: @Jozef a non-UCM merge remains the most direct workaround, I believe.

Comment: Not sure how a non-UCM merge would help me? The changesets of those Activities have already been delivered. After that happened, additional versions were added to them (which we do not want delivered) which makes them appear as delivery candidates at each deliver (which we want to avoid as it confuses the developers).

Comment: @Jozef it would help as it would allow you to merge the right activities (the one you want) while ignoring the other activities (the one you don't want). Since it is a non-UCM merge, you are allowed to pick the activities you need without being limited by UCM timeline forcing you to include other activities as "candidate".

Comment: I see what you mean, However, ClearCase does not force us to include those Closed Activities. Apparently, those undelivered changes do not have dependencies with the rest of the code base. It's just that they continue to show up in the list of delivery candidates every time we do a deliver and have to uncheck them. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @Jozef Hence my reference to **timeline**, which explains why those activities keep showing up as candidate even though there is no codebase dependency: http://stackoverflow.com/q/684895/6309